# numpy.array: resulting data type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

numpy makes it easy to translate python objects into numpy ndarrays, and will even pick an appropriate resulting data type if one is not specified:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

If the object being translated doesn't fit into one of the predefined numpy data types, this happens:

```
>>> b = np.array([1,2,100000000000000000000000000000000000000])
>>> b.dtype
dtype('O')
```

My question: does numpy provide an interface to determine the `dtype` of a variable that would result from a call to `array`, without actually having to create a new numpy variable in the process?  Specifically, if the result of a call to `array` is not going to be one of the integer or floating point numpy data types, I don't care about the returned value, and would rather not take the memory to store said result and then discard it.